# A comparison between the words "revolting", "repugnant" and

Tags: word-meaning

> Please help me to find the best words (possibly interchangeable synonyms) from among the words in the list bellow:
>
> - 11 million people were killed during the Holocaust. This has been one of the most ......... actions of all time.
>
> **Explanation:** I need one or more adjectives from my listed ones which directly indicate "a feeling of strong dislike and hate, but not 'horror'; just 'hate'".
>
> **-1-** disgusting
>
> **-2-** revolting
>
> **-3-** repulsive
>
> **-4-** repugnant
>
> For me '**disgusting**' and '**revolting**' mean the same and mean '**something nauseating**". But what I'm going to use here has nothing to do with 'the feeling of nausea'! I'm going to imply a feeling of '**strong dislike and hate**' when you see or hear or somehow come across such a seen or such an event. I think both "**repulsive** and "**repugnant**" imply exactly the same meaning in my question.
>
> Do you confirm me?

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is an Off Topic opinion-based "beauty contest". There is no "best word" to describe something like the Holocaust - probably the only thing most people can agree on is that [6 million Jews died, not 11 million](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Holocaust) (it doesn't include all those combatants and civilians who died in Russia, Africa, the Far East, etc.). You could check out [what others have written](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+holocaust+was+the+most%22+%22history%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) after the words *the holocaust was the most...*

Comment: Dear @FumbleFingers, first of all I have to thank you because of your concern and good attention; but I have to say that here is not a place of deliberation about a historical event. I am not a Jewish and where I live often people do not know anything about this historical disaster and people because of the political forces and beliefs even do not think of these things, let alone considering them. And I for one am not going to discuss about it. Just having a little search in Google you will easily find the number of the killed people about 11 million where 6 million of them where Jewish.

Comment: Key word: how many people were murdered in the holocaust.
Result: 11 million people were killed during the Holocaust (1.1 million children). 6 million of those victims were Jewish. Other groups targeted by the Nazis were Jehovah's Witnesses, homosexuals, disabled people, and Roma.

Comment: Anyway here is a place where you'd better as a native help me as a non-native person to learn your mother language to expand and prolong it and not a place for punishment people due to their lack of knowledge. Though I am sure that it was a misunderstanding. Every aware humane being believes this disaster and I am very sorry because of mentioning to this catastrophe. Please forgive me and if you consider it correct, please kindly change my question with another topic and content.

Comment: *Repugnant* is the best choice of the four given.  It is often used to convey the sense of *moral* odiousness.

Comment: @TRomano thank you very much for your response. But what about 'repulsive"? Does it imply the same thing? Meanwhile do you confirm my understanding of the words "revolting" and "disgusting"?

Comment: I know the relevant Wikipedia article says ***many** [almost certainly not **most**] historians use a definition of the Holocaust that includes the additional five million non-Jewish victims of Nazi mass murders, bringing the total to approximately eleven million*, but if you check a selection of dictionaries you'll find they almost all define the word much more specifically - e.g. OED *the mass murder **of the Jews** by the Nazis in the war of 1939–1945.* I'm not arguing figures, just pointing out the normal definition of the word today.

Comment: *Disgusting, revolting, and repulsive* are often used interchangeably in a figurative sense that mingles the nauseating with that which is morally or socially offensive.The visceral element is missing only from *repugnant*.

Comment: Why these four words, and not words like _reprehensible_ or _deplorable_? Is this an exercise from a workbook or something?

Comment: @J.R. not at all. I just found these words from my dictionary and have never come across your suggested words. But based on their meanings I don't think that one can substitute them for "repugnant" in this specific sense. :)

Comment: @A-friend - It depends on what you are trying to emphasize. Personally, I think that, in most cases, _deplorable_ would be a better word to describe the holocaust than _repugnant_.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with some definitions - these all from Google as an example will reveal that technically there is not much difference between these words:

*Disgusting*: arousing revulsion or strong indignation.

*Revolting*: "causing intense disgust; disgusting"

*Repulsive*: "arousing intense distaste or disgust" or "of or relating to repulsion between physical objects"

*Repugnant*: "extremely distasteful; unacceptable" or "in conflict with; incompatible with."

---

Now...

*Disgusting* to me brings up an idea of a sickening feeling in your stomach.  Though of course it is used to describe many things other than food, smells, etc.  It comes from a French word meaning "taste" (*dis*- being a negative prefix).

*Repulsive* is derived from *repel* (Latin) which means to push away.

*Revolting* is derived from Latin *revolvere* which means to "roll back."

*Repugnant* to me immediately brings up an idea of a bad smell.  This is from a French word meaning *opposing*.

So really, *repulsive* and *revolting* are about the same exact thing.  *Disgusting* is more about a physical sensation than a general want to be away from something.  *Repugnant* means to reject something strongly.

To be honest though, none of these words (at least by themselves) are strong enough to describe something that is among the worst things that has happened in human history, and the netural word "actions" would make any word weaker in that regard.

I would call this an *atrocity* (pl. atrocities), and a word to describe could be *horrific*.